# Datetimepicker unable to select the todaydate

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Datetimepicker unable select today's date.Suppose When we open the datetimepicker and change the date and select the today date it is not selected.And we used the Bootstarp datetimepicker.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker().data("DateTimePicker").options({format: "DD/MM/YYYY",minDate:new Date()});
```

Thank you.

Comment: try this code:-`$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: "DD/MM/YYYY",startDate:new Date()});`

Comment: `minDate:new Date()` allows you select today , can show your code where this is not working in a fiddle

Answer (score 6):

**You have to integrade use Below code  to select the todaydate**

```
minDate: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)
```

> $("#startdatetimepicker").datetimepicker({ minDate : new
>   Date().setHours(0,0,0,0),format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'});

- It select the today's date also after picked another date and go for select today's date.
- It's also disable the previous date.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the minDate to today, which means won't be able to select it.

Instead, set minDate to

```
 minDate: moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0)
```

which will be today.
for more info : https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1302#issuecomment-141923309

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `minData` to `new Data()`

`new Data()` by default gives the current data.

So In your case you are not able to select not only today's date but all the past date.

So simple remove the `minData` parameter(as below), or use it a different way.

`$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker().data("DateTimePicker").options({format: "DD/MM/YYYY"});`

Comment: In this case we able to select the previous dates too.So that's y we used the minDate.Is there any solution for this(Not select previous dates) @sanjeev

Comment: @vamsikr As the Datetimepicker uses Moment, the best way to get yesterday is `moment().subtract(1, 'day')`

Answer (score 0):

You should use following code.

```
 <script src="/assets/js/plugins/datetime/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> 
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    weekStart: 1,
                    todayBtn: 1,
                    autoclose: 1,
                    todayHighlight: 1,
                    startView: 2,
                    minView: 2,
                    forceParse: 0
                });
```

Comment: Still unable to select the today date@Singh

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `minDate` to today, which means won't be able to select it.

Instead, set `minDate` to `minDate: moment().subtract(1,'d')` which will be yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the date as a string and the rest will be handled by the library itself

```
moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD')
```

or

```
new Date().toDateString()
```